# Multiple directives need to share same private scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives, one is restricted to the element and the other to an attribute

```
<bar-foo special></bar-foo>
```

Now the issue is that the **special** directive need to define something on the scope of the `barFoo` directive. However, the **barFoo** directive has a private scope

```
angular.module('App')
.directive('barFoo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><h1 ng-if="doit">Bar Foo</h1></div>',
        scope: { /* private scope */ },
        ....
    }
});
```

The `doit` value is set by the **special** directive

```
angular.module('App')
.directive('special', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that **barFoo** has a private scope, and `doit` is not added to that scope (but the $parent). I was wondering if it is possible to let the **special** directive have the same scope as the **barFoo** directive ?

I can only think of the following solutions, 1) add an extra attribute

```
<bar-foo special doit="doit"></bar-foo>
```

or 2) change the template html of **barfoo** to

```
<div><h1 ng-if="$parent.doit">Bar Foo</h1></div>
```

Although this works great, it feels a bit like a work-around!

Comment: Anytime I came across $parent it was an indication that I was doing something in a way it was not meant to be. You seem to have the same feeling. I would personally go for the first solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested solutions are not a workaround and are in fact an acceptable way of doing what you need here.

AngularJS directive provides the facility of isolated scopes for a good reason. Considering you want to use a directive multiple no. of times as a replicated element, you want to make sure that the scope remains isolated from all other scopes.

Besides the 2 solutions you suggested, there can be a 3rd solution as well:

Create an angularjs `service` that holds your `doit` variable. Create service methods to `get()` and `update()` this variable.
You can then inject this `service` in both of your directives and share the `doit` variable in your directives by calling the service methods. This way, regardless of what kind of scope you use in your directives, you can be assured that you share the same `doit` variable.

Note that angularjs `service` are singletons and hence everytime you invoke a get() or update() on the service, you are dealing with the same instance of your `doit` variable.

Comment: +1 for the service suggestion; that's really the best solution here.